# On the derivative of the inverse of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

I tried to prove it like this
$$y=f(x)$$
$$x=f^{-1}(y)$$
$$dx=(f^{-1})'(y)dy$$
$$dx=(f^{-1})'(y)f'(x)dx$$
$$(f^{-1})'(y)=\frac{1}{f'(x)}$$
Does it lack rigor just because I am using differentials?
Is the last step valid nevertheless?
What about passing from considering $y$ an "independent" variable then reconsidering it as a function of $x$?

Comment: "Does it lack rigor just because I am using differentials?" Yes.

Comment: To give a meaning to $dx$ so that your equalities stand a chance to make any sense at all requires far more work than to prove the formula that you are trying to prove.

Comment: It lacks rigour because you *suppose* that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable (which is true only if $f'(x)\ne 0$ anyway).  So you only obtained what the formula should be, in case $f^{-1}$ is differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the right regularity assumptions on $f$ it is in fact a consequence of the chain rule
$$(g \circ f)'(x) = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$
applied to $g = f^{-1}$: We have that $g \circ f$ is the identity, thus its derivative is constant $1$. On the other hand, by the chain rule, 
$$(g \circ f)'(x) = g'(y) \cdot f(x),$$
from which we can conclude that 
$$(f^{-1})'(y) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}.$$

Your answer lacks rigor in that it is just a syntactic manipulation (also the last step). Using the chain rule is kind of the formalization of your last idea.

Answer (score 2):

$$y=f(x)$$
Differentiate with respect to $y$ 
$$ 1=f'(x)\frac {dx}{dy}$$

$$\frac {dx}{dy}=\frac {1}{f'(x)}$$